# Control status does not update in validate NG_VALIDATORS

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular6, angular5

I want to do something when the control status changes. I am using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and NG_VALIDATORS. The validate function gets the control but the values don't seem to change.

Sample code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-formcontrols-oqmwqg

Line 50 never happens in json-input component.

I want the action to happen in the component, not outside.
If you make the textarea empty, the control is invalid but status in validate never updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ngControl inside your component(JsonInputComponent) by angular **Injector** and listen to the statusChange event to get an updated status. Please have a look at below updated code:-

You can try something like below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-formcontrols-oqmwqg

Comment: there are no changes? you need to fork it

Comment: Sorry, please have a look on below link:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-formcontrols-oqqlpx